# Arranging figures horizonatlly

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I was wondering if there was an easy way to arrange multiple matplotlib.pyplot **figures** horizontally in jupyter-lab other than using subplots. The figures are generated one-by-one by a module using a syntax similar to

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(N):
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.plot(...)
```

I cannot easily change the code for the module but it's kinda annoying that jupyter-lab arranges the figures from top to bottom. Can I somehow change this behaviour?

Comment: I should clarify once more: I have no influence on how to create the figures themselves. I was just wondering if there was maybe a neat solution using **jupyter-lab** to just display the figures side-by-side instead arranged vertically

Answer (score 0):

following the information at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

```
# sphinx_gallery_thumbnail_number = 11

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
```

to arrange two plots side by side

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, -y)
```

or to stack them in two directions

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0,0]')
axs[0, 1].plot(x, y, 'tab:orange')
axs[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,1]')
axs[1, 0].plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
axs[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1,0]')
axs[1, 1].plot(x, -y, 'tab:red')
axs[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1,1]')

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='x-label', ylabel='y-label')

# Hide x labels and tick labels for top plots and y ticks for right plots.
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.label_outer()
```

so in your example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, N)
for i in range(N):
    axs[0, i].set_title('plot '+str(i))
    axs.plot(...)
```

Comment: I am very well aware of this solution, unfortunately it is not applicable in my case. As I tried to convey, I have no way of directly accessing to plotting itself. The creation of the figures and the plot calls are all handled within a module. All I want to do (even though I realize that might be quite challenging) is to display the individual figures side-by-side instead to arranged veritcally...